# Tango won't update to Nash

Tags: google-project-tango

I am currently using Project Tango in UK. I tried to use system update to upgrade to Nash release, but it shows "your system is up to date". I am sure the device is currently in Libnitz. Is Google blocking OTA out of USA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using Tango from France, and typically my Tango detects/receives each update about 1 week after the official release date, whatever the reason. (I let the device on, with internet access through Wifi, during my daily devs). I'm currently in Leibniz (1.10) waiting the latest 1.11 to be detected/downloaded.
By the way, if you just get a NEW tango, the gap of software between it and latest release may be important : for instance, the latest new Tango we get last month was in January 2015 software version (i.e. a few month gap, so).
Hope it helps. ;-)

Comment: @phil0stine I haven't received OTA yet, it's "up to date".

Comment: Ok thanks @Minimalist Im in the same boat. I received mine the day you posted. I figure I will contact support if OTA is not ready tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

OTA is not blocked by Country, It should be OK for you to download in UK or France. 
Please check on this weekend to see if you got the Nash OTA updated.
you can also contact project-tango-help@google.com, if you still can't get OTA updated.

also I suspect 1.11 should be Leibniz and 1.13 : Nash.
1.12 Mandelbrot was skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed project-tango-help@google yesterday because my system didn't update to Nash but the Project Tango Core app from the Play store did. Their response was to wait until this weekend. I'm in the US.

Comment: Hi, I got my update this morning. I think they are sending out update in different batch. Just wait until this weekend. Also I notice that Nash update do produce more depth point(like 1.5x or 2x) but tracking is worse than before. Could you check on these after you get update?

Comment: My system updated today morning and I tried the Tango Explorer (Pointcloud) app and did notice the pointcloud was denser. It's hard to tell how well/poorly tracking is doing since I didn't look at how it was doing in Leibniz.

Answer (score 1):

after a week off, my Tango has downloaded the 506.9 MB of Nash Release update this morning (my location is France). My feedback testing it on my cloud acquisition app : no visible benefit on cloud points density. I'm doing more test....